# Minimizing cross entropy vs minimizing negative probabilities

Tags: machine-learning, cnn, loss-function

1. The cross entropy loss can be written as $L_1 = -\sum_i\sum_c y_{ic}\log P_{ic}$, where $i$ represents images and $c$ are the classes. $y_{ic}=1$ for the correct class.
2. Instead of L_1 I can minimize the following $L_2 = -\sum_i\sum_c y_{ic}P_{ic}$

When I use these as the loss functions to CNN I found that for a particular problem $L_2$ performs significantly better than $L_1$. However, I am unable to explain it. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Could you please confirm that the loss function in 2 is what you are referring to as L2

Comment: Also please share distribution of 0s and 1s in your dataset if that's ok

Comment: I am using a weighted loss. I have 6 classes. So we can assume that all the classes contains almost equal number of images.

Comment: I am actually surprised by the results. While the first loss function because if we are wrongly predicting the probability for the true class to be very less. The log of a small number will be positive and hence the loss increases and thus fixes it.

Comment: In second case we are just making the value of negative as much as possible and solving it. The only reason I can think of is that we are penalizing the error with the true P value in L2 which is between 0 and 1 in this case vs 0 and infinity in the case of L1.  My assumption is if any class is under represented L1 cannot wrongly predict that class still but L2 can ignore that class.

Comment: It's an interesting problem. Please keep me posted if you find a reason.